# Swizzle and render target in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I am a rendering in a render target with a R8 texture as a color attachment. Is there a way to output a float4 in the shader and have the alpha swizzled in the R Component.

I know its doable when you want to read the the texture with the swizzle in the ImageView. I can't make it work when I write to the texture.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot swizzle writes to images. But you're in the shader, and the shader clearly knows that it is writing only a single value. And since we know that single value textures put the single value in the "red" component, that's where it should write it.

Comment: Thanks for the answers , too bad its doable on a PS4 and kind of on openGL.

Comment: @BertrandCavalie: Writing pixels to a framebuffer in OpenGL doesn't respect the texture swizzle.

Comment: That's why I said kind of,  you have access to a A8 format which does the trick